# 2 shot strategy and kshot strategy algorithm for selling stocks

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, binary-search

The classic maximize stock profit questions involves an array with stock prices and you are required to return the max profit that can be made:

I understand the logic for maximizing profit for given stock quotes. In a simple way, we can maintain a running min and a running max_so_far and we check if current elem is less than min or current elem - running min is greater than max_so_far and if yes, we update our max_so_far

We finally return our max_so_far which is the maximum profit that can be made.

Now, how do we solve the problem for 2 shot strategy? Basically you are required to return i0, j0, i1, j1 such that sum of arr[j0]-arr[i0]  and arr[j1]-arr[i1] is maximum and also i0<j0 < i1 <j1

I was able to think to a certain extent but couldnt figure out later how I could generalize it. So, 1st I could get the single shot solution array containing all the max_so_far elems. Similarly, I could do a similar array but starting from arr[n-1] to 0. This tells me if I have to sell after today, what is the max profit that I can make. If I add the corresponding elements in array in forward iteration and array in backward iteration and I get the max element out of it, then that corresponds to max i0,j0,i1,j1

But can someone first explain the logic for k shot algorithm. I guess I'll then want to understand k-shot strategy as to how I can extend the 2 shot strategy to k shot.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One generalization is to keep a 2k+1 element array where the j<sup>th</sup> entry (counting from zero) is the maximum cash on hand after j transactions alternately buying and selling. If j is even, then the next transaction is to buy. If j is odd, then the next transaction is to sell.

Initially, the array is 0, -inf, -inf, ..., -inf (negative infinity means that the entry is infeasible). When the next price p comes in, update the elements at indices 2k, 2k-1, ..., 1 in order as follows. The best transaction for 2k is the max of (i) the previous entry, signifying 2k previous transactions (ii) the entry for 2k-1 plus p, signifying 2k-1 previous transactions followed by selling at p. The best transaction for 2k-1 is the max of (i) the previous entry, signifying 2k-1 previous transactions (ii) the entry for 2k-2 minus p, signifying 2k-2 previous transactions followed by buying at p. Continue to alternate plus and minus.

I'll leave the problem of recovering the buy/sell timing as an exercise.